# Returning the collection Oracle SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql

So I have a function which I am trying to return a bunch of mobile numbers for each team. The problem is, the numbers being returned are all the same rather than being different for each team (see output)
[screen print of output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M5iiz.png)

Could you give any pointers to where I may be going wrong?

Thanks.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE BODY TeamType AS
MEMBER FUNCTION get_tel_num (numberType IN VARCHAR2)RETURN VARCHAR2 IS
prefix VARCHAR2(5);
d_code VARCHAR2(4);
main_number VARCHAR2(7);

CURSOR team_cursor IS
    SELECT ta.intl_pref, ta.dial_code, ta.p_number 
    FROM Team t, Table(t.tel_nos) ta
    WHERE ta.number_type = numberType;
BEGIN
IF NOT team_cursor%ISOPEN THEN
    OPEN team_cursor;
END IF;
LOOP
    FETCH team_cursor INTO prefix, d_code, main_number;
    EXIT WHEN team_cursor%NOTFOUND;
    RETURN prefix ||'-'|| d_code ||'-'|| main_number;
END LOOP;
CLOSE team_cursor;
END;
END;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the design on your function's signature:

- Input: `numberType` (e.g. mobile)
- Output: `VARCHAR2` (i.e. the number)

Given that, and the definition of your `WHERE` statement at the `team_cursor`, there is no way for your function to know whom this number is for. Therefore, based on your `LOOP` body, you just return the first result of your cursor, which happens to be the same number with every call you make to the function.

One solution to that is to add one more parameter to your function that takes an identifier of the team member to which the inquired phone number belongs. Use this parameter in your `WHERE` statement of the `team_cursor` to get the number of that particular team member.

Comment: So I have just tried doing what you have said and my results appear to still be the same, where I am not getting the corresponding teams number, I am still getting the same number which outputs every team. Furthermore, if I run the query used in the function on its own, it delivers the results I require.

Comment: As an addition, I would like to be able to not use a parameter to identify which team. I have an object of `TeamType` which has an `ARRAY` of `phoneNumber` types, I would like to identify the team it wants based on the Team record within the table `INSERT INTO Team
VALUES ('', '', '', '', PhoneArrayType(PhoneType('Mobile', '+44', '191', '3258761'), PhoneType('Business','+44', '191', '0874912'), PhoneType('Home', '+44', '191', '8703916')));` Is generally what an insert would look like for the table... Hope this makes it a little clearer what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: @Tuvo The solution suggested above is comprised of two steps: (1) define a new parameter that identifies the team number and (2) use the value of this new parameter in your cursor's WHERE statement. If you do so and if your relations are structured in a way such that each team will have one number of each numberType, and if you don't have one dummy phone number assigned to all teams, then your function should return one different phone number depending on the selected type and the selected team. Could you please confirm that you did both steps and that are my assumptions are valid?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to return a cursor so that the calling program can fetch all of the rows.

http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/static.htm#LNPLS494